# Given a non-measurable set $E$ with finite outer measure, show that there exists an open set $P$ with the following property:

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $E$ be a non-measurable set with finite outer measure.  Show that there exists an open set $P$ with finite outer measure such that $E \subseteq P$ and $m^{*}(P \setminus E) = m^{*}(P) - m^{*}(E)$

My attempt at a proof:

Let $m^{*}(E) = m$

Since $E$ must be a bounded set, there is a countable collection of open sets $\{I_k\}$ which serves as a cover for $E$.  Then, $E \subseteq P = \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}I_k$.

We can decompose $P$ into $(P \setminus E) \bigcup E$, then $m^{*}(P) = m^{*}((P \setminus E) \bigcup E) \leq m^{*}(P \setminus E) + m^{*}(E)$

Thus $m^{*}(P \setminus E) \geq m^{*}(P) - m^{*}(E)$

I'm not sure how to get rid of the equal sign.  Does this seem like its on the right track?

Comment: My first instinct is to show that for any $\epsilon > 0$, we can find set $P_\epsilon$ such that $m^* (P_\epsilon) - m^* (E) \leq m^*(P_\epsilon \setminus E)  < m^* (P_\epsilon) - m^* (E) + \epsilon$. This may be a complete waste of time, but would logically show the desired result.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676853/outer-and-inner-approximation-of-set-with-finite-outer-measure?rq=1 may be useful

Comment: @erfink I think Ninoslaw wants an open set.